# ERROR! No argument passed to command module

Tags: ansible

This is my `nodes` file:

```
[servers]
server1
server2
server3
```

Which names are derived from `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host: server1
  HostName: 1.1.1.1
  Port: 1111
  User: root
Host: server2
  HostName: 2.2.2.2
  Port: 2222
  User: root
Host: server3
  HostName: 3.3.3.3
  Port: 3333
  User: root
```

This is my `playbook.yaml`:

```
- hosts: servers
  tasks:
    - name: show hostnames only
      shell:
        cmd: hostname

    - name: Copy csf files
    copy:
        src: {{ item.src }}
        dest: {{ item.dest }}
        mode: preserve
    with_items:
        - { src: /etc/csf/csf.conf, dest: /etc/csf/csf.conf }
        - { src: /etc/csf/csf.allow, dest: /etc/csf/csf.allow }
```

At first I want to make sure only the `playbook` works fine, and then copy some files into all `servers` group but I get this error after `ansible playbook.yaml`:

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: playbook.yaml
### some help commands of ansible ###
Some actions do not make sense in Ad-Hoc (include, meta, etc)
ERROR! No argument passed to command module
```

Comment: A playbook have to be launched with the executable `ansible-playbook`, the command `ansible` is for [_ad hoc_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_guide/intro_adhoc.html) commands as the error clearly says it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get this error after `ansible playbook.yaml`

It's like you didn't read fully [the introduction guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_playbook.html#create-and-run-your-first-network-ansible-playbook).
The right command line should be:

```bash
ansible-playbook -i nodes playbook.yaml
```

Also in your playbook, there's a mistake… according to your `nodes` file…

```
- - hosts: regions
+ - hosts: servers
```